# updating security rules through rest api

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to update security rules through rest api? I have been trying to update rules by trying to update parts of the "rules" location but have been getting 400 response code.

Len

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a PUT to the following endpoint:

```
https://YOUR_FIREBASE.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json?auth=FIREBASE_SECRET
```

For example, with curl:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{ "rules": { ".read": true } }' https://YOUR_FIREBASE.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json?auth=FIREBASE_SECRET
```

You can get your Firebase Secret from the "Auth" panel of Forge (i.e. go to https://YOUR_FIREBASE.firebaseio.com/ and click the "Auth" page)

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was missing the .settings in the path. I was able to replace the entire rules as in your example once corrected the path. Is it possible to update just some part of the rules, e.g. https://YOUR_FIREBASE.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules/users/bob/name.json? I still seen to have trouble doing that (400 code).

Comment: No, that's not possible unfortunately. You have to set it all at once. The rules are intended to be something you deploy along with your code, so live updating pieces wasn't something we decided to support. You can always download the whole thing, change a piece, and upload it again.

Comment: To update from a file ```curl -X PUT -d @file https://YOUR_FIREBASE.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json?auth=FIREBASE_SECRET```

Comment: Note that if your file has newlines you may need --data-binary instead of -d