# Possibility to manage all existing users with firebase simple login

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I am using firebase simple-login in my angularjs-app. 
Is there any possibility to manage all existing user accounts (not with forge console)?

An admin-user should be enabled to edit and delete these accounts.

Answer (score 1):

When you allow (for example) Twitter users to log in to you Firebase application, **all** Twitter users can log in to your Firebase application. You can't directly control specific user accounts, unless you [implement your own custom authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/simple-login/custom.html).

What you do have control is over **what** those user accounts have (read and write) access to. You do this through [Firebase's security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/). If you'd remove an accounts read/write access from all your data, you've essentially locked them out of your Firebase.

You can programmatically set the security rules through the REST API. See [updating security rules through rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590788/updating-security-rules-through-rest-api).

Comment: The `password` provider, however, is a special case and those accounts can be deleted either through the dashboard or via the API.