# Read and write security rules from Firebase admin API

Tags: java, firebase-admin

I am looking for a way to read and write the Firestore, Storage and other Firebase products security rules using the Firebase Java admin SDK.

I cannot find any documentation about it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure if [the answers of this old and similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590788/updating-security-rules-through-rest-api)  are still working, but it is worth a try.